# Can't synchronize time, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync, date-time, ntp, clock

Ok, I finally installed Windows 7, clean install.  Time synchronization does not work. Clicking "Update now" gives message:

`Unable to start the Windows Time service. Please try again later.`

I use **time.nist.gov**, as I believe that use to be reliable, and works for my XP pc's.

Any hints on this?

I did edit the Task Scheduler,

Microsoft > Windows > Time Synchronization > SynchronizeTime

where I set it to synch every 6 hour (I need accurate clock), but this problem was also before I made that change. And this scheduler doesn't set the time either, as far as I can see..

Comment: Please [avoid using stratum 1 servers](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/RulesOfEngagement) unless necessary. For a personal computer, `pool.ntp.org` or `<country>.pool.ntp.org` is accurate enough.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that Windows Time Service could not be started.

1. Check if Windows Time Service is disabled. If yes enable it and set it to Automatic (open Run prompt and type "services.msc".Navigate to Windows Time, right click, select Properties and change Startup to Automatic).
2. Try manually starting Windows Time Service (open Run prompt and type "services.msc"). Navigate to Windows Time right click and click Start. If it does not start properly, check the event log for the error.

If there is an error in the event log, update the question with the error.

UPDATE: Try http://www.worldtimeserver.com/atomic-clock/ first.

Comment: The error messages usually get dumped to Event Log, at `eventvwr.msc`.

Comment: Ok, it was set to Manual, and was not running. So I sat it to Automatic, and started it. However, I still get the same error. Do I need to restart my system? Not sure where to look in the Event Log, I never used that before.

Comment: Open Run Prompt. Type eventvwr. Click on Application. See if any error is logged. Now click on System. See if any error is logged.

Comment: Hmm. I can't see any related errors. Is this windows Time Service supposed to run all the time? Even though I set it to automatic, after system restart, it still is not started. Then when I start it, and go to the Internet Time Settings dialog, it says time was updated (at that time), however time is still incorrect. And still gives the error message when I try to Update now manually.

Comment: Windows Time runs all the time. Can you check if it is running under LocalSystem account? You can do this in services.msc

Comment: Under "Log On As" column, it's listed as "Local Service", if that's what you meant..

Comment: Can you change that to LocalSystem? Right click -> Properties -> Log on tab -> Set it to Local System and then start the service.

Comment: When trying to start as LocalSystem, I get: Windows could not start the Windows Time service on Local Computer. Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.

Comment: Try this: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/atomic-clock/

Comment: Ok, it says Windows 7 32bit, I'm running 64 bit, not sure if that will be a problem.

Comment: I am out of options :). You can try it even though it says Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer here ...

After many failed attempts to sync with various time servers I came to realize time sync problems were caused for lack of an initial sync reference point. After manually synchronizing from cmd|posh I was then able to use the gui app to sync ...

Powershell ...

```
 cd $env:systemroot\System32 

 .\net stop w32time
 .\w32tm /unregister 
 .\w32tm /register
 .\sc config w32time type= own
 .\net start w32time
 .\w32tm /resync /computer:$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

You should get a response such as ...

```
Sending resync command to {$computername} ...
```

Afterwards the gui interface should succeed ...

Comment: The `w32tm /unregister` command gives me `Access denied` errors. Any idea why?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Are you in an elevated prompt?

Comment: I suppose. I'm on an administrator account, and it doesn't seem to work even if I right click and select "Run as administrator".

Comment: Is the service running? @SEE Ganesh's answer to ensure the service is actually running... > administrator > services.msc ...

Comment: [The service is running](http://i.imgur.com/vAE48fN.png).

Comment: Sorry @MatheusMoreira ... I'm not sure buddy.

Comment: The following error occurred: The interface is unknown. (0x800706B5)

any idea?

Comment: @Ascherer Are you in an elevated shell?

Comment: "Run as Administrator"? yeah

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error "Access is Denied"; however using Microsoft's Fixit available at this [MS Fixit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738995%28WS.10%29.aspx) a synchronisation mode became available in the Tab "Internet Time" where I was able to sync manually (tho it automatically syncs on a schedule) and change time servers